# Right approach to choose which directive to print Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is the scenario.

I'm making a `$.get()` request to the server to get to know what is the role of the user, eg if the user is `administrator`, a `normal` user or a `user with elevated privileges`. Once I get that value from the PHP `$_SESSION` I return a json object which I then parse and start checking if it is any of the users mentioned above:

```
$scope.getMenuType = function(){
        $.get('controllers/getUserType.php', function(result){
            dataForHubMenu = $.parseJSON(result);
            console.log(dataForHubMenu);
            if(dataForHubMenu.userType == 'normal'){
                $scope.menuType = '<normal-menu></normal-menu>';
            } else if(dataForHubMenu.userType == 'admin'){
                $scope.menuType = '<administrator-menu></administrator-menu>';
            } else if(dataForHubMenu.userType == 'director'){
                $scope.menuType = '<director-menu></director-menu>';
            }
        });
    };
```

Then I trigger my function inside the controller on the line below:

```
$scope.getMenuType();
```

Once I do this, I expect that my variable `$scope.menuType` has the right jQuery object to print. And so inside my HTML I do the following:

```
<div ng-controller="HubController as hub" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="well">
                <h1 class="text-center">Panel de Control</h1>
                <hr>
                {{hub.menuType}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside the Chrome console I try to `console.log()` the value of `menuType` to see if the variable has any value, this is what I get:

```
console.log(angular.element($(".container")).scope().menuType);
undefined VM2228:2
undefined
```

The `console.log()` occurs inside the controller and inside the console on chrome, the output is the same on both cases.

I'm not sure why this is happening. My directives are as follow:

```
app.directive("AdministratorMenu", function(){
    return {restrict: 'E', templateUrl: "views/admin-menu.html"}
});
app.directive("normalMenu", function(){
    return{restrict: 'E', templateUrl: "views/normal-menu.html"}
});
app.directive("directorMenu", function(){
    return{restrict: "E", templateUrl: "views/director-menu.html"}
});
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Is this the right approach to do what I'm trying to do. I'm just finished with the angular course @ codeschool and I'm trying it out with advanced features in this small project.

Comment: Not really sure why you're doing HubController as hub for that controller attr. If your controller is linked, it should just be {{menuType}} without the hub object.

Comment: @Christopher Marshall It still doesn't print the jQuery object. And I'm trying to figure why.

Comment: Are your breakpoints being hit in that if statement? Then set a breakpoint on $scope.menuType and see if it's being assigned the return.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall no it is not being assigned. Is it possible that because the jQuery object doesn't technically exist, it ignores it? I console.log my dataForHubMenu and it logs what I need, including the role of the user.

Comment: When you trigger your function with this line: `$scope.menuType = $scope.getMenuType();`, even though you assing another value to `menuType` inside the function body, after its execution the function return (undefined) is assigned to `meuType`. Just call the function, don't assing its return value to anything.

Comment: Just fixed that. It doesn't print undefined anymore, but now it doesn't print anything at all. Just a blank space perhaps.